# Crop a remote image using ImageResizer in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crop, imageresizer

Is there anyway to crop a remote image using ImageResizer in MVC4?

I have a MVC4 project that using ImageResizer to crop image on any page for the UI, but it's just for local images, how to use it for the remote images from other server like google or facebook?

**EDIT:**

Maybe I need to get the remote images to my local server then crop it the way I want, can any1 help me how to get the remote image and save it to my local server?

Comment: Very simple answer, you can't. Best thing you could do is get all of the images you want and store them locally. Or I suppose you could write c# to grab all of your images and then re-size them. EDIT: If you're just changing the dimensions, and not worrying about file size, then you can resize any image (local or remote) with CSS

Comment: I got the same idea, to get the remote image to my local then crop it, can you show me how to get a remote image with an URI?

Comment: What is your use case here? Are you trying to grab them and crop the images to reduce file size? Or simply display them with proper dimensions?

Comment: both of them, reduce the file size and crop it to fit my UI :)

Comment: Have you tried the RemoteReader plugin? This is what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageResizer offers the [RemoteReader plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/remotereader), which allows you to dynamically crop and process remote images.

[Disk caching of output (and source images, if high-latency)](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache) is reccomended and can be easily enabled.